# With Tkinter in Python. How do I call a list variable into a canvas one at a time

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

With Tkinter in Python. How do I call a list variable into a canvas one at a time when a button's pressed (in this case. *next*). Here's what I tried. I'm a newby in programming.

```
def _next_(self):
    def y(self):
        a='hey'
        b='you'
        e=[a,b]
        for i in (e):
            while True:
                 print i
                 break
    x=y
    self.ques = self.canvas1.create_text(380,40, text= self.x())
```

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

textList = ["Hey", "you", "whatsup"]

mycanvas = Canvas(root)
mycanvas.pack()

textobj = mycanvas.create_text(100, 50)

def f():
    mycanvas.itemconfig(textobj, text=textList)

mybutton = Button(root, text="Click", command=f)
mybutton.pack()
```

?